# When i remove overflow:hidden property from my navbar it disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make my own responsive navbar, can someone explain why is this happening why is my nav disappearing. When i resized it to certain size it is gone, but what is puzzling me is that overflow hidden property because with it it works fine and i dont know why...can someone explain this to me  Here is the code

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 6px 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar a.toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.toggle {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle" onclick="myFunc()">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>

  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: check answer may be it will work for you. fiddle also included.

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned height adding height will solve your issue.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 50px;
}

.navbar a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 6px 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar a.toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.toggle {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle" onclick="myFunc()">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using flexbox

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 15px;
}

.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 4px;
  margin: 6px 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar a.toggle {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .navbar a {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar a.toggle {
    margin-left: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle" onclick="myFunc()">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <div class="icon"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```